# How does the reference to the "Lord of Glory" in 1 Corinthians 2:8 relate to the Book of Enoch?

Tags: jesus, 1-corinthians

> None of the rulers of this age understood it. If they had known it, they would not have crucified the **Lord of glory**. NET  1 Corinthians 2:8

> And he said unto me: 'Enoch, why dost thou ask me regarding the fragrance of the tree, and why dost thou wish to learn the truth?' Then I answered him saying: 'I wish to know about everything, but especially about this tree.' And he answered saying: 'This high mountain which thou hast seen, whose summit is like the throne of God, is His throne, where the Holy Great One, the **Lord of Glory**, the Eternal King, will sit, when He shall come down to visit the earth with goodness. And as for this fragrant tree no mortal is permitted to touch it till the great judgement, when He shall take vengeance on all and bring (everything) to its consummation for ever. It shall then be given to the righteous and holy. Its fruit shall be for food to the elect: it shall be transplanted to the holy place, to the temple of the Lord, the Eternal King. [Chapter 25:1-5]  BOOK OF ENOCH  From-The Apocrypha and Pseudepigrapha of the Old Testament R.H. Charles Oxford: The Clarendon Press

> Then I blessed the **Lord of glory**, and said, "Blessed are you, Lord, the one of righteousness, ruling forever."
> 1 Enoch 22:14 Old Testament Greek Pseudepigrapha

> In the last ages, in the days of the true judgment before the righteous for all time here. The impious will bless the **Lord of glory**, the eternal king.  1 Enoch 27:3 Old Testament Greek Pseudepigrapha

> Then I blessed the **Lord of glory**, and I declared his glory and I sung a hymn majestically.  1 Enoch 27:5 Old Testament Greek Pseudepigrapha

Answer (score 3):

"Lord of Glory" is part of a collection of titles of Jesus and God such as:

### **Lord of Glory**

- 1 Cor 2:8 - None of the rulers of this age understood it. For if they had, they would not have crucified the **Lord of glory**.
- James 2:8 - My brothers, do not with partiality hold the faith of our **Lord Jesus Christ of glory**.

### **God of Glory**

- Ps 29:3 - The voice of the LORD is over the waters; the **God of glory** thunders; the LORD is heard over many waters.
- Acts 7:2 - And he began to speak: "Men, brothers, and fathers, listen! The **God of glory** appeared to our father Abraham, being in Mesopotamia, before his dwelling in Haran,

### **King of Glory**

- Ps 24:7-10 - **7** Lift up your heads, O gates! Be lifted up, O ancient doors, that the **King of Glory** may enter! **8** Who is this King of Glory? The LORD strong and mighty, the LORD mighty in battle. **9** Lift up your heads, O gates! Be lifted up, O ancient doors, that the **King of Glory** may enter! **10** Who is He, this King of Glory? The LORD of Hosts— He is the **King of Glory**.

### **Father of Glory**

- Eph 1:7 - that the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the **Father of glory**, may give to you a spirit of wisdom and revelation in the knowledge of Him,

The designation of Jesus Christ as the "Lord of Glory" is consistent with other passages of the NT:

- Matt 19:28 - And Jesus said to them, "Truly I say to you that in the regeneration, when the Son of Man shall sit down upon **His throne of glory**, you having followed Me, you also will sit on twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel.
- Matt 25:31 - And when the Son of Man comes in His glory, and all the angels with Him, then He will sit upon His **throne of glory**.
- John 17:5 - And now, Father, glorify Me in Your presence with the **glory I had with You** before the world existed.
- Luke 24:26 - Was it not necessary for the Christ to suffer these things and to enter into His glory?"
- Phil 3:20 - For our citizenship exists in the heavens, from whence also we are awaiting a Savior, the Lord Jesus Christ,
- Phil 2:9-11 - Therefore God exalted Him to the highest place and gave Him the name above all names, that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, in heaven and on earth and under the earth, and every tongue confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

Thus, Jesus' title of "The Lord of Glory" simply says that Jesus came from, and returned to heaven in the presence of God the Father.

**1 Enoch**

The phrase "Lord of Glory" applying to God, written in pre-Christian times (the inter-testamental period) in 1 En 22:14, 25:3, 27:3, 5, 36:3(4), simply shows that this designation for God was common in those days and consistent with OT usage as shown above.

The fact that "Lord of Glory" is applied to Jesus is simply a comment about the exalted view that NT writers had of Jesus Christ.

Answer (score 1):

It is a direct parallelism and identification. Just like the Lord Jesus Christ identifies Himself with the Lord of David of the Psalm 110:9, so here Paul identifies the enthroned God, the Lord of Glory, with Jesus Christ crucified.

In Psalms there are other places where, like in Enoch's given passage, there is a mention of God, the enthroned King, who is anointed by God (Psalm 45:6-7). Now, this also resonates with the Enoch's saying, as well as the Christian interpretation that there this God, anointed by God is Jesus Christ incarnated. Being called "God" He is put on equal level with God and is co-worshipped; being said to be anointed by God, it means that He is not a different source of Godhead, but that He totally derives from the Father.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it probably doesn't really relate to the Enoch.

That the English phrase "Lord of Glory" appears in some English translation(s) of 1 Corinthians and in some English translation(s) of 1 Enoch, doesn't necessarily imply that Paul must be citing 1 Enoch.

---

The Greek phrase in 1 Corinthians is 2:8 is Κύριος ὁ τῆς δόξης (*Kyrios ho tēs doxēs*).  The exact same phrase appears in the Septuagint twice, in the Psalms:

> ἀναβήσεται ὁ Κύριος ἐπὶ τὴν ὑπερύψωσιν, **Κύριος ὁ τῆς δόξης**
> στήριξις ἡμῶν (Psalm 23:7 LXX)

> Ἐξομολογησάσθωσαν τῷ Κυρίῳ τῷ ἐν Σιὼν, ὅτι ἐπέβλεψεν καὶ ἐπέσκεψεν τῇ
> γῇ, **Κύριος ὁ τῆς δόξης** ὑψώσας τὰς ὀπίσω ἐν ᾠσμῇ διὰ τοῦ μὴ εἶναι
> ὑπερηφάνους (Psalm 68:17 LXX)

1 Enoch was written originally in Aramaic.  Based on how the text corresponding to Κύριος ὁ τῆς δόξης in the Septuagint is rendered in the Targum, the Aramaic would be
מַלְכָּא דִּיקְרוֹ (*Malka di-Ikro*).  This phrase does not appear anywhere in 1 Enoch, so it would not seem that Paul is *literally* referring to anything in 1 Enoch.

Perhaps there is some figurative allusion, but if Paul really had 1 Enoch in mind, he probably would have quoted something more directly, as was the case when he referred to canonical Old Testament texts.

On the other hand, Paul almost always quoted from the Greek Septuagint and not the Hebrew, so a better test would be to see if there was the match to some ancient Greek manuscript of 1 Enoch, but these are fragmentary.